# WCF - WebInvoke POST - object parameter

Tags: wcf, rest, serialization

I have the following WCF REST web service interface :

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        UriTemplate = "foobar/",
        Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare),
    ]
    void PostFoobar(Foobar foobar);
}
```

The implementation :

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public void PostFoobar(Foobar foobar)
    {
        try
        {
            Log.MonitoringLogger.Info("foo" + foobar.foo);
            Log.MonitoringLogger.Info("bar" + foobar.bar);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (Log.ExceptionLogger.IsErrorEnabled) Log.ExceptionLogger.Error(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

My Foobar class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Foobar
{
    [DataMember]
    public string foo { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string bar { get; set; }
}
```

But it seems my Foobar object in parameter is always NULL when I call it from a client. I tried to implement the following method :

```
void PostFoobar(String foo, String bar);
```

And this time it works ! So my question is : Why, when I send a JSON Foobar object, it does not deserialized it ?

Here is a capture made with Wireshark to see if my client sent really the JSON object I expected :
[image: wireshark capture]

So it seems the client send the object as expected : { "foo": "foo text", "bar": "bar text" }

Comment: Would it help to mark the `Foobar` class as a `DataContract`, and its properties as `DataMember`s?

Comment: Thank you, I tryed but still the same problem. I have updated my post with the code of my Foobar class

Answer (score 0):

I found something interesting: It works with the chrome plugin *Simple REST client*. I sent the json data:

```
{ "foo": "foo text", "bar" : "bar text" }
```

and it has worked.

So I have analysed the logs of my IIS server, and I found a difference : No  element is catched from my client. The following object (in the logs)

```
<root type="object" xmlns="">
  <foo type="string">foo chrome</foo>
  <bar type="string">bar chrome</bar>
</root>
```

Appears only when I call my service from the chrome client.